# Subsorting without losing first sort order?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have list of recharge plans with name and amount like this

```
Top-Up 80
Add-On 56
Add-on 60
Top-Up 20
Recharge 45
Top-Up 121
Add-On 9
Recharge 34
```

**I expect sorted  output like this**

```
Add-On 9
Add-On 56
Add-On 60
Recharge 34
Recharge 45
Top-Up 20
Top-Up 80
```

Sort based on name and subsort based on amount.
I tried this but not get expected result.

```
 Collections.sort(rechargePlans, (o1, o2) -> {

            String x1 = ((RechargePlan) o1).getRechargeShortDesc();
            String x2 = ((RechargePlan) o2).getRechargeShortDesc();
            int sComp = x1.compareTo(x2);

            if (sComp != 0) {
                return sComp;
            }

            Integer x11 = ((RechargePlan) o1).getRechargeAmountInteger();
            Integer x22 = ((RechargePlan) o2).getRechargeAmountInteger();
            return x11.compareTo(x22);
        });
```

I lost alphabetical sort order when applying the amount based sort .

Comment: I lost alphabetical sort order when applying the amount based sort

Comment: What type of data structure is `persons`?  What class?  Your sort code looks fine to me, so at this point you should give us something reproducible.

Comment: Are name and short description different? It seems your code would sort on short description first (I see no error in it), which will not give you alphabetical sorting on names, of course. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: name and short decription is same

Comment: List<RechargePlan> rechargePlan is the collection

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you expect alphabetical sorting by name and secondary sorting by amount.

However your code sorts by short description and then by amount. It doesn’t seem to be the same thing (unless name and short description are the same). In particular, if the short descriptions of your objects happen to be identical (for example empty strings or some default short description), your code will sort by amount only.

Comment: Some  empty strings came for the short description. I resolved that issue .And working perfectly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
Collections.sort(persons, 
    // first by short description
    Comparator.comparing(RechargePlan::getRechargeShortDesc)
              // then by recharge amount
              .thenComparing(RechargePlan::getRechargeAmountInteger));
```

In order for this to work, there needs to be a `Person implements RechargePlan` relation, and `person instanceof List<? extends RechargePlan>`.

Comment: It’s what I would do too, but whether it’s an option for the asker, depends on Android API level. And I suspect that it will not solve the asker’s issue. It seems it’s just a terser version of the same code.

Comment: @OleV.V. I assumed his use of a lambda meant he could use Java 8... is that different for Android API? And yeah, it is the same code, I was just pointing out the terser version. The actual important bit is the last sentence because that's what needs to be fulfilled for the code to work.

Comment: Good points. And I agree that your code is better and less error-prone (I admit I had not paid attention to the lambda when writing my first comment).

Comment: The above code only support from android version 24. I faced some issues for building even after adding  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)

Comment: I there any alternative code that support from api level 19